# grails: one field, multiple classes

Tags: grails

I would like to track a Motor with a Grails application. At several occasions, the location of the motor changes, but the location type also changes. How do I efficiently store the current location?

A first attempt would be:

```
class Motor {
    String motornumber
    Locationtype lt
}

class Locationtype {
    String type
}

class Machine {
    String machinenumber
}

class Repaircompany {
    String companyname
}
```

Depending on `Locationtype lt` which is ONE of `{"Machine","Repair"}`, a Motor object shall store the machine id or the repaircompany id at which the motor is located at. "Machine" means: The Motor is deployed on a machine, "Repair" means: the Motor is currently being repaired.

So I would like to have a field `location` as a field inside `Motor`, but of which type? I know, each time I access `location`, I would have to evaluate `lt`.

I was thinking about a field inside a trait. Would I be off-track with that or is that the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions here, and none is necessarily better than another based on the limited information provided.  Two possible solutions:

Simplest: Add a nullable `Machine` field and a nullable `Repaircompany` field to the `Motor` object.  Then either could be populated (or technically both) and you can work as needed from those values.

Likely better: Create a `Location` base class (can be abstract) and extend `Machine` and `Repaircompany` from it.  In `Motor`, create a field of type `Location` which could then be populated with either subclass.

For either solution, you probably don't need a `Locationtype` any more.  You can determine that via which field is populated (for solution 1) or via subclass (for solution 2).

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel  for your answer. The purist's route would be to create the abstract class, but I think the solution with the nullable fields will be what I will try, because that's easier to handle as regards the UI: In the view, with the help of some JavaScript/jQuery, I easily can chose which dropdown to make visible, depending on the state of the dropdown visualizing the field `Locationtype lt`. Having implemented that, `lt=="Machine"` means: Machine dropdown field visible, Repaircompany dropdown not visible and so on ... Ok, now I have a clear vision, thanks again!

Comment: Just another feedback - as the vision was so clear, I had no difficulty writing down the concept and then implementing the solution. And I found even another advantage of the "nullable fieilds solution", which is to interpret a motor as junk when both fields Machine and Repaircompany are null. I'm thinking about removing the `Locationtype lt` as it is a bit redundant, because the null pattern between the fields is the information itself: Both fields filled: invalid, one field filled: valid, both null: valid & junk. That was a good week - thank you again.